# netty: the http file example can not work with apache bench when keep-alive is enabled

Tags: java, http, netty, keep-alive

The http file example under test:
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file

I compiled the above example with netty-4.1.0.beta8.

```
My test result:
$ ab -k -n 2 -c 1 -v 6 http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.sh
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)...INFO: POST header == 
---
GET /test.sh HTTP/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
Accept: */*


---
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 462
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 06:34:52 GMT
expires: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 06:35:52 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=60
last-modified: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 02:35:40 GMT
connection: keep-alive


LOG: Response code = 200
LOG: header received:
**MY TEST.SH CONTENT**

WARNING: Response code not 2xx (500)
apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 1 requests completed
```

It seemed that my test.sh content is considered to be the second request's headers.

My further test:

```
$ ab -k -n 1 -c 1 -v 6 http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.sh 
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)...INFO: POST header == 
---
GET /test.sh HTTP/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
Accept: */*


---
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 462
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 06:39:02 GMT
expires: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 06:40:02 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=60
last-modified: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 02:35:40 GMT
connection: keep-alive


LOG: Response code = 200
..done


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /test.sh
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.005 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    1
Total transferred:      263 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    209.25 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4.779 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.779 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          53.74 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
          min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:     5    5   0.0      5       5
Waiting:        5    5   0.0      5       5
Total:          5    5   0.0      5       5
```

You can see the document length is 0 byte.

I run similar commands against www.google.com and it works fine. 
Could you please help on this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work if `-k` is removed?

Comment: yes.  My server closes the non keep-alive http connection after sending each response.  In that case the ApacheBench knows that it's the end of the socket input stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in ApacheBench.

ApacheBench does not follow the http specifications fully, and assumes headers have a certain capitalization. Because the headers returned by the netty application doesn't have the character case ApacheBench expects, it assumes a default of 0 bytes for the content length.

**[Http specification 4.2:](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)**

> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names
>   are case-insensitive.** The field value MAY be preceded by any amount of
>   LWS, though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be extended
>   over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one SP
>   or HT. Applications ought to follow "common form", where one is known
>   or indicated, when generating HTTP constructs, since there might exist
>   some implementations that fail to accept anything beyond the common forms.

Because the keep-alive switch of ApacheBench forces it to assume the server supports keep alive, it doesn't detect a "missing" header for the keep alive packet.

This problem if however something that should be solved in ApacheBench, as it is a bug in that application that causes it to miss the proper content-length.